# Anyone know a good collection of YAML tests?

Tags: testing, yaml

I'm writing (another) YAML parser in CoffeeScript.  Having finished the parser-writing part and testing it with a few handwritten examples, I'm wondering if anyone's yet created a good suite of input/output tests for 'generic' YAML.

Basically I want something like https://github.com/norman/haml-spec, and if anyone knows of any such thing, let me know!

Comment: YAYAMLP?  (Sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: @RossPatterson The notification got me excited there :P